# Update specific values in a object with a conditional

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to update some values ​​of an object with conditionals, is there a way to do it without iterating all the elements?

This code works but I want to do the same more efficiently with a query, search method or something like that

```js
const testObj = () =>{
  let objAttrDay = {
   "1":{
      "sunday":false,
      "recurrentSunday":false
   },
   "2":{
      "sunday":true,
      "recurrentSunday":false
   },
   "3":{
      "sunday":true,
      "recurrentSunday":false
   }
};
let contSunday = 3;
if(contSunday >= 3){
for(let i in objAttrDay){
    if(objAttrDay[i].sunday){
        objAttrDay[i].recurrentSunday = true;
    }
}
}
console.log(objAttrDay);
}
testObj();
```

Comment: replace all the `objAttrDay[i]` with just `i` and it should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: thanks, this question "How do I loop ...?" it is very similar, my question is to do query and search without using loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) breaks down an object into an array of key, value pairs. Then you can easily map that array to another array with the `recurrentSunday` property set how you want. Then recreate your object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). You will need a browser that supports `entries` and `fromEntries`, which were introduced in ECMAScript 2019.

```js
const testObj = () => {
  let objAttrDay = {
    "1": {
      "sunday": false,
      "recurrentSunday": false
    },
    "2": {
      "sunday": true,
      "recurrentSunday": false
    },
    "3": {
      "sunday": true,
      "recurrentSunday": false
    }
  };
  let contSunday = 3;
  if (contSunday >= 3) {
    let entries = Object.entries(objAttrDay);
    entries = entries.map(([key, value]) => {
      return [key, { 
        ...value,
        recurrentSunday: value.sunday
      }];
    });
    objAttrDay = Object.fromEntries(entries);
  }
  console.log(objAttrDay);
}
testObj();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two fairly clean ways of replacing values in JS objects and arrays that I can think of.

**Option 1 - create a new Object**

Let's assume that we have an object like the one you defined above.

```
    let objAttrDay = {
      "1":{
        "sunday":false,
        "recurrentSunday":false
      },
      "2":{
        "sunday":true,
        "recurrentSunday":false
      },
      "3":{
        "sunday":true,
        "recurrentSunday":false
      }
    };
```

we can change the value of "recurrentSunday" to true like this.

```
    objAttrDay = {
           ...objAttrDay, // deconstruct all previous values from this object
           "3": {
                ...objAttrDay["3"], // we could also just write `"sunday": true`
                "recurrentSunday":true // change value to true
            }
          };
```

You'll find that the only change made to the *objAttrDay* Object is the value of `objAttrDay["3"]["recurrentSunday"]`

**Option 2 - Change the value of a specific key in your existing Object**

Alternatively, we can select only the value that we want to change, like so:

`objAttrDay["3"]["recurrentSunday"] = true`

The first option is useful if you would like to create a new object to store your values which is popular in reactjs and often necessary if the initial object is immutable. (Like state or props).

If, however, you don't need to create a new object, I would recommend the second method as it is short, succinct, and will likely save processing power.

**Example of your if statement with the second option.**

```
if(contSunday >= 3){
   objAttrDay["3"]["recurrentSunday"] = true;
};
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let objAttrDay = {
  "1": {
    "sunday": false,
    "recurrentSunday": false
  },
  "2": {
    "sunday": true,
    "recurrentSunday": false
  },
  "3": {
    "sunday": true,
    "recurrentSunday": false
  }
}

const updateObject = (contSunday, object) => 
    Object.keys(object)
    .filter((key) => key >= contSunday)
    .map((key) => { return {key, ...object[key]}})
    .filter((item) => item.sunday)
    .map(({recurrentSunday, ...i})=> { return {recurrentSunday:true, ...i}})
    .map(({key, ...item})=> {object[key] = item; return object})


let result = updateObject(3, objAttrDay)
console.log(result);
```